# Go through tangled list of binary records in memory using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following .bin file

```
1f ac 00 78 00 3f 00 c3 00 83....
```

and I'm supposed to go through it using pointer arithmetic. I'm supposed to grab the first byte that will tell me how many "words" I'm going to process, then every two bytes will tell me the offset where I'm supposed to begin reading. My problem is that I get the first byte without any problem, but now all I'm trying to do is to increase my pointer so that it points to `ac`, cast it to a `uint16_t`, print that value out, do some procedures and now I want it to point to `78`. Here's what I have written so far:

```
 Pre: Buffer points to a region of memory formatted as specified.
      Log points to an opened text file. 
 Post: The target of Buffer has been parsed and report written as specified
uint8_t doStuff(uint8_t *Buffer, FILE *Log) // given function parameters
{
    int wordsToProcess = *(Buffer); // get that first byte
    uint16_t offset = 0;
    bool firstTime = true;

    for  (int i = 0; i < wordsToProcess; i++)
    {
        if (firstTime)
        {
            Buffer++; // I've tried Buffer += 1;
            offset = *((uint16_t*)Buffer); // casting turns into little endian.
                                           // I want 00 ac but I'm not getting that

            fprintf(Log, "Looking for %0X words, starting at %0X\n",
                    wordsToProcess, offset);

            firstTime = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Buffer += 2;
            offset = *((uint16_t*)Buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

I've even deleted almost everything from the hexdump except the first two bytes and I still get `66`. I've also tried by making a pointer have the same address as `Buffer` and go from there because I thought maybe playing around with `Buffer` was causing me problems, but same deal. Could anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you say you "have" a "hex dump" do you mean it's a file containing binary data?  Or is the file actually text like you posted?  As for your endianness problem, consider using `ntohs()`.  It would help if you post the exact expected output of the program for your given sample input.

Comment: Don't mix the logic like that, the `firstTime` variable makes the loop do two entirely different things. That's confusing, grab the metadata outside the loop, and then loop through the data to display it. The loop block should do JUST ONE THING !!! Display the data.

Comment: it's a .bin file; opening it looks something like this: 1fac 0078 003f 00c3 0083 0057 00a4....

Comment: You're not going through the hex dump. You're going through the binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what might be the problem, because it might be that the data is not what you expect it to be. But your code has some issues IMHO.

This is how it would be more readable and easier to understand, mantain and thus (*easier to write with less bugs*).

```
uint8_t
doStuff(uint8_t *buffer, FILE *log)
{
    int wordCount = *buffer++;
    uint16_t *pointer = (uint16_t *) buffer;
    uint16_t offset = *pointer++;
    pointer += offset;
    for  (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++)
        fprintf(log, "0x%04X ", *pointer++);
    return 0 // I don't know what you want to return;
}
```

Please note that if, the data does not have the expected structure this code would cause *Undefined Behavior*.